# Add a Dynamic Transparency (opacity) to Vertical Text Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the css I'm working with:

```
figure p {
opacity:0;
}

figure:hover p {
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
transition: opacity 0.35s;
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 /* Starting position */
 -moz-transform:translateY(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateY(100%);    
 transform:translateY(100%);
 /* Apply animation to this element */  
 -moz-animation: scroll-up 5s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: scroll-up 5s linear infinite;
 animation: scroll-up 5s linear infinite;
}
/* Move it (define the animation) */
@-moz-keyframes scroll-up {
 0%   { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes scroll-up {
 0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}
@keyframes scroll-up {
 0%   { 
 -moz-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 transform: translateY(100%);       
 }
 100% { 
 -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
 transform: translateY(-100%); 
 }
}
```

It scrolls the text up nicely, but I can't figure out how to make a gradual opacity transition. As apparent from the above code, I tried adding this to the hover style:

```
 opacity:1;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
transition: opacity 0.35s;
```

The resulting style on the page is not what I expected. The text just appears suddenly. This is a bummer, because what I'm really after is to have a dynamic opacity. In other words, the higher the text, the more transparent it should become. Once it reaches the highest point in the vertical scroll (the text scrolls from bottom to top), it will be 100% transparent (aka 0 opacity). So I'm a bit apprehensive because as I said above, I can't even get a simple opacity transition to work.

**Question:** Is there a means for such a style given my current vertical scroll style?

Comment: i think you can't do this in css alone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```css
p {
  opacity: 0;
}

.figure:hover p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Starting position */
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */
  -moz-animation: scroll-up 8s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: scroll-up 8s linear infinite;
  animation: scroll-up 8s linear infinite;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */

@-moz-keyframes scroll-up {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50%,60%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll-up {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateYsa(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50%,60%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scroll-up {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50%,60%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="figure">
  Hover here
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's close to what I want, thanks! Part of the problem could be my articulation of my desired style. With your solution, once the animation reaches the top, the whole thing turns transparent. I have a something like a bullet list, and I want each item in the list to become transparent once it reaches the top (individually). I'll adjust the post for clarity.

Comment: in all fairness your solution got the original question done. I had a hard time trying to put the style and feel of my goal into words. I'll accept your answer and maybe make a new post later if I still can't figure the individual `<p>` part out.